# Monotonicity of vector fields

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, vectors, vector-fields, monotone-functions

If I have a vector field $(x,y,z)$ on a one dimensional line ($x$-axis) and if I have to check its monotonicity between two intervals. Will it be monotonic if:

(1) only one of the components of vector field is monotonic in that interval.
**OR**
(2) two of the components of vector field are monotonicaly increasing and the other is monotonicaly decreasing in that interval.
**OR**
(3) all the components of vector field are either monotonicaly increasing or monotonicaly decreasing in that interval. .

> NOTE: I have read [this article here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-monotonic-vector) but haven't got the answer I am looking for.

Comment: You would need an order on $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a first step. Not sure if that cited one is a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ is your interval, and for each $t\in I$ your vector field at $t$ is $\big(x(t), y(t), z(t)\big)$, all you need to do is check that for each $t\in I$

$$x(t) < y(t) < z(t),$$

or the analogous inequalities with $>$ instead of $<$.
These conditions can be met regardless of whether each individual coordinate function is increasing, decreasing or not monotonic at all.